# Use of direct object pronoun in “que l'on peut”

Tags: pronoms

I came across the phrase from the title while listening to a French song, the full verse was:

> Que l'on peut boire au creux des ruisseaux

Could anyone explain why the phrase in the title uses a direct object pronoun? It seems to have the same meaning of *Que on peut*, though is the pronoun mandatory here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually the definite article, as opposed to the direct object, but regardless it has no meaning. It's an optional, formal addition for [euphony](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/on-vs-lon/), to avoid *qu'on* (which is pronounced like **con**).